# Null pointer exception thrown by sessionfactory in spring and hibernate

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, sessionfactory

Exception while assigning the session factory

```
 java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.span.hotelmanagement.persistance.CustomerDAOImpl.saveCustomer(CustomerDAOImpl.java:41)
    at com.span.hotelmanagement.business.CustomerRequestManagerImpl.saveUser(CustomerRequestManagerImpl.java:30)

    at com.span.hotelmanagement.controller.CustomerBean.saveCustomer(CustomerBean.java:121)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.jboss.el.util.ReflectionUtil.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtil.java:328)
    at org.jboss.el.util.ReflectionUtil.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtil.java:273)
    at org.jboss.el.parser.AstMethodSuffix.getValue(AstMethodSuffix.java:59)
    at org.jboss.el.parser.AstMethodSuffix.invoke(AstMethodSuffix.java:65)
    at org.jboss.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:96)
    at org.jboss.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:276)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:105)
    at javax.faces.event.MethodExpressionActionListener.processAction(MethodExpressionActionListener.java:148)
    at javax.faces.event.ActionEvent.processListener(ActionEvent.java:88)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.broadcast(UIComponentBase.java:775)
    at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:300)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:786)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1251)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:81)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:118)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:593)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:503)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:421)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1070)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:611)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:316)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

ApplicationContext xml

```html
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
 xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee"
 xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
 xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p" 
 xmlns:task="http://www.springframework.org/schema/task"
 xsi:schemaLocation="
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd 
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd 
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee 
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee-3.2.xsd
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx 
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.2.xsd
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/task
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/task/spring-task-3.2.xsd
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.0.xsd">
  
 <context:component-scan base-package="com.span.hotelmanagement">
  <context:include-filter type="aspectj" expression="com.span.hotelmanagement.*" />
</context:component-scan>
 <context:annotation-config />
 <!-- Newly changed query -->
 <!-- <context:property-placeholder location=classpath:database.properties/> -->
 
 <!-- <bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource"
   p:driverClassName="${jdbc.driverClassName}" p:url="${jdbc.url}" p:username="${jdbc.username}"
   p:password="${jdbc.password}"/>-->
 
    <!-- Create DataSource Bean -->
      
   <!--   <bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
        <property name="jndiName" value="java:comp/env/jdbc/TestDB"/>
    </bean> 
     -->
 <!-- <jee:jndi-lookup id="dataSource"
    jndi-name="java:comp/env/jdbc/hotelmanagement" expected-type="javax.sql.DataSource" />
     -->
     
     <bean name="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/hotelmanagement" />
    <property name="username" value="root" />
    <property name="password" value="Root@1234" />
   </bean>
 <bean id="sessionFactory"
  class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
  <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
  
   <property name="configLocation">
   <value>./WEB-INF/hibernate.cfg.xml</value>
  </property> 
  <!-- <property name="configurationClass">
            <value>org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration</value>
        </property> -->
  <property name="hibernateProperties">
   <map>
    <entry key="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect" />
    <entry key="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />
    <!-- <entry key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create"/> -->
   </map>
  </property>
 </bean>
 <tx:annotation-driven/> <!--transaction-manager="transactionManager"--> 
 <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager" 
          p:sessionFactory-ref="sessionFactory" />   
 <!-- <bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.CustomScopeConfigurer">
  <property name="scopes">
   <map>
    <entry key="view">
     <bean class="com.span.hotelmanagement.common.SpringViewScoped" />
    </entry>
   </map>
  </property>
 </bean> -->
 
   <bean id="viewResolver"
  class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
  <property name="cache" value="true" />
  <property name="viewClass"
   value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" />
  
 </bean>
 
 
 <task:annotation-driven />
</beans>
```

Customer DAO Impl class

```
    package com.span.hotelmanagement.persistance;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.List;
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
import com.span.hotelmanagement.entity.CustomerEntry;

@Repository
public class CustomerDAOImpl extends AbstractGenericDAOHibernate<CustomerEntry, Long> 
implements CustomerDAO,Serializable{

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -276032705968481483L;

/*  @Autowired
    @Qualifier("sessionFactory")
    public SessionFactory sessionFactory;*/

    public void deleteCustomer(CustomerEntry customer) {


    }

    public CustomerEntry saveCustomer(CustomerEntry customer) {

        CustomerEntry cObj=null;
        Session session =null;
        try
        {
            session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();

            AbstHibernateUtil.CreateSession(sessionFactory);
            AbstHibernateUtil.beginTransaction();
            if(customer != null)
            {
                cObj= new CustomerEntry();
                cObj=(CustomerEntry)save(customer);
            }
            //AbstHibernateUtil.commit();
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
        e.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally{
            AbstHibernateUtil.endTransaction();
            AbstHibernateUtil.closeSession();
        }
        return cObj;
    }

    public List<CustomerEntry> getCategoryList() {
        return null;
    }
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub


}
```

while debugging the code seesionFactoru.getsession returns the null value. Please help me with as it is stopping the further implementation

Comment: Please provide your `CustomerDAOImpl` and spring configuration and explain what are you going to achive. Posting only exception should make this question close.

Comment: hi i have posted all the related classes

Answer (score 1):

Alright so you have in your spring configuration this:

```
<bean id="sessionFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />

         <property name="configLocation">
            <value>./WEB-INF/hibernate.cfg.xml</value>
        </property> 
        <!-- <property name="configurationClass">
            <value>org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration</value>
        </property> -->
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <map>
                <entry key="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect" />
                <entry key="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />
                <!-- <entry key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create"/> -->
            </map>
        </property>
    </bean>
```

That means spring is managing your sessionFactory.

But in your code you have something like this(this is big no no):

```
//What is this ? You dont need to care about creating session here otherwise you will have serious problem with transaction management and besides that you can see other exceptions
 AbstHibernateUtil.CreateSession(sessionFactory);
```

How it should look like:

```
    @Repository
    @Transactional
    public class CustomerDAOImpl extends AbstractGenericDAOHibernate<CustomerEntry, Long> 
    implements CustomerDAO,Serializable{

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -276032705968481483L;

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("sessionFactory")
    public SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    public void deleteCustomer(CustomerEntry customer) {}

    public CustomerEntry saveCustomer(CustomerEntry customer) {
        CustomerEntry cObj=null;
        Session session =null;
        try {
            session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
            if(customer != null){
                cObj= new CustomerEntry();
                cObj=(CustomerEntry)save(customer);
            }
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return cObj;
    }

    public List<CustomerEntry> getCategoryList() {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Another thing you dont need to worry about your transaction management. Since you have told to spring that:

```
<tx:annotation-driven/> <!--transaction-manager="transactionManager"--> 
    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager" 
                p:sessionFactory-ref="sessionFactory" />
```

You dont need to manually start `AbstHibernateUtil.beginTransaction();` and end
`AbstHibernateUtil.endTransaction();`. You need to mark your class `CustomerDAOImpl` or method `saveCustomer` as `@Transactional`

Another problem is this: `AbstHibernateUtil.closeSession();`. When you defined in spring `sessionFactory` bean you told him something like that: *I dont care about opening and closing session. Spring you need to do this now*. So now this: `sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();` is exactly what you need. Nothing more.

You should move `sessionFactory` to this class `AbstractGenericDAOHibernate` since not only `CustomerDAOImpl` uses factory.

Hope this clears some of your problems for now.

Comment: Updated with `sessionFactory`